# How to migrate data between Postgres Servers which both need password?

Tags: postgresql

I try to use the command to migrate data between two PG servers, but both need password:

> pg_dump -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname

Then I get the error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "database" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Is there any option to solve the issue? I'm not sure how to specific the password in the command.

Comment: You can put the passwords into `.pgpass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) to store the passwords for both databases, then the PostgreSQL client will be able to connect to both without prompting for a password.

The password file would look like this:

```
localhost:5432:dbname:localuser:password1
remotehost:5432:dbname:remoteuser:password2
```